# O que está ilegivel para o python?

Tags: python-3.x

Gostaria de saber o que exatamente está errado nesse código python:

```
import urllib.request
page = urllib.request.urlopen("http://beans-r-us.appspot.com/prices-loyalty.html")
    text = page.read().decode('utf8')

price = 99.99
while price > 4.74:
    where = text.find('>$')
    preçoinicial = where + 1
    preçofinal = preçoinicial + 5
    price = text[preçoinicial:preçofinal]
print("Buy")
```

A mensagem de erro é a seguinte:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "starbuzzpreçocafe.py", line 7, in <module>
while price > 4.74:
TypeError: unorderable types: str() > float()
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Você está comparando *string* com *float* depois da primeira iteração.

A solução é converter o texto extraído sempre para *float*:

```
price = float( text[preçoinicial:preçofinal] )
        ^^^^^
```

Ficando assim:

```
import urllib.request
page = urllib.request.urlopen("http://beans-r-us.appspot.com/prices-loyalty.html")
    text = page.read().decode('utf8')

price = 99.99
while price > 4.74:
    where = text.find('>$')
    preçoinicial = where + 1
    preçofinal = preçoinicial + 5
    price = float( text[preçoinicial:preçofinal] )
print("Buy")
```

> Nota: como observado pelo @Miguel, nos comentários, teria que ser:
>     `preçoinicial = where + 2`
>     para não pegar o `$` que é localizado pelo find, e o `preçofinal` ajustado de acordo com o número de dígitos que você está esperando, para que não venha nenhum caractere a mais.

Além disso, precisa tomar cuidado caso não exista preço menor que o indicado, algo do tipo:

```
price = 99.99
where = 0
while price > 4.74 and where >= 0:
    where = text.find('>$')
```

Tem jeito melhor ainda, que é colocar o teste do `where` dentro do `while`, aí precisa ver o que é melhor para seu caso real. Talvez você queira fazer alguma lógica para não mostrar o "buy" se o `where` for negativo.

Comment: Sugeriria também evitar caracteres como `ç` nas variáveis. Até funciona, mas pode dar alguma dor de cabeça dependendo do editor de código e sistema em que abrir. Se se mantiver nos caracteres ASCII, vai ter uma preocupação a menos.